# .NET app.config file -- does this need to be distributed with my app?

Tags: c#, .net, settings, app-config

I'm ready to release my first .net app, but I'm trying to determine if the `{myAppName}.exe.config` file that is created at build time needs to be distributed with my app? Or will this be created if it doesn't exist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

What is in it? You will probably want to open it up and look and see what in there-- various design time components will modify it, often without you knowing. As soon as you have 1 dependency on the config file, you need to include it, and it is possible that the dependency originates from a framework or 3rd party assembly.

Comment: I'm using the in-built settings functionality; this is where my program settings are stored.  It has all of the appropriate keys for my program settings, I'm just not sure if the file needs to be distributed with my executable.

Comment: Ah, then yes. If you want to keep the config out of the hands of meddling users and administrators, you must put that stuff in the assembly, registry, resources, database or somewhere else. I tend to think of user and admin editable config as a feature not a defect, tho.

Comment: sir, i have used connection string in the app.config file, which is used by the form.cs to establish connection to database, how do i put this app.config file in a assembly , resources? please help

Comment: @MatthewMartin --sir, i have used connection string in the app.config file, which is used by the form.cs to establish connection to database, how do i put this app.config file in a assembly , resources? please help

Comment: @DaveShaw  --sir, i have used connection string in the app.config file, which is used by the form.cs to establish connection to database, how do i put this app.config file in a assembly , resources? please help

Comment: @sqlchild If you want to ask a new question, it is better to create a new question. Anyhow, here is a link describing how to use resource files to store strings. http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20020405.asp

Comment: Note: default values for [settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/a65txexh(v=VS.140,d=hv.2).aspx) are in the exe/dll, so you don't need to include the app.config file just for those (there may be other reasons, as said).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes, include it.  You don't want to take the chance that you don't need it.  There are a number of things you might need it for.  If you don't have it, your application will have issues.  If you don't need it, it won't hurt anything to have it there.